# How i can use auto Attence system using by django and postgresql

Tags: django-postgresql

i want to use functionality when the employee enters in office and mark the attendance with the help of button-like i have Attendance page where the employee hit the button the time store into Attendance-In Column and when the Employee left the office time the Attendance marked and store into Attendance-out column in the database using by Django. how it's possible. I tried too many times but i did not get success